# rails associations with multiplicity

Tags: ruby-on-rails, associations, multiplicity

The question is: how to represent a multiplicity in Ruby on Rails associations? 
Suppose I have two models - **Collection** and **Item**. They are in **has_and_belongs_to_many** relations. If a collection contains multiple identical instances of items (say, it contains 10 identical items), how should I do this?

I made a try with **has_many :through**, but it seems to be not very nice approach.

Answer (score 0):

First I want to clarify that you really want a many-to-many relationship, and not simply a one-to-many where there are **duplicate** DB records to represent the multiplicity. Because you could, if it's okay, simply duplicate the `items` records as many times as necessary and point their `collection_id` foreign key to the appropriate `Collection` record.

If that's not what you want, and you truly do want a multiplicity, then I wouldn't use ActiveRecord associations to do this. I would simply store an array or list of `item_ids` in `Collection` objects, and serialize/deserialize this array to a string or text field in the database such that:

```
collection.item_ids
=> [2, 3, 1, 1, 2, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 5, 6, 2, 3, 2]
```

Where each entry in the `item_ids` attribute is a foreign key to the `items` table.

If you happen to be using Postgres as your DB I think you can actually store the list/arrays as a [Postgres `array` column](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/static/arrays.html), though I've never actually tried to do this in Rails myself.